# PHP updating user information

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form where user can change his personal information that is already in database.
What is the best solution to update only the database fields which are changed and not all avaliable form options.

If you have any better suggestion than putting everyting in one form, please tell.

Comment: Are you using any kind of framework?

Comment: PHP / MYSQL on wamp server, no frameworks, writing code in notepad.

Comment: The only real fool proof way to do this is to validate/compare the new data against the original data at the server side after the new data has been submitted. Which means you either have to `SELECT` again before you `UPDATE`, or store the results of your original `SELECT` in some kind of session.

Comment: Update every field in the form even if they are unchanged. This way you'll only need 1 query statement and values that are updated with the same value as before doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update the whole user record, not taking care of which fields have changed and which ones have not.**

Updating all fields at once is roughly as time- and memory- efficient as querying to check which fields have changed. Actually, you just waste your time checking the fields one by one to see which ones updated. So there is no point in such checks before updating.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming MySQL and that you don't mind using sessions, here is a way to do it:

```
<?php

  // Start the session
  session_start();

  // The name of the table in the database
  $table = 'table_name';
  // The primary key of the record we are dealing with
  $id = 1;
  // The name of the column that holds the primary key
  $pkCol = 'id';

  // Connect to database somewhere here and store it in $conn

  if (!empty($_POST['update'])) {

    // Update the record

    // Compare values from $_POST with values from $_SESSION and build an array of data that has changed
    $changes = array();
    foreach ($_SESSION['original_data'] as $colName => $value) {
      if ($_POST[$colName] != $value) {
        $changes[] = "$colName = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST[$colName])."'";
      }
    }

    // Build the query
    $query = "UPDATE $table SET ".implode(', ', $changes)." WHERE $pkCol = {$_SESSION['record_id']}";

    // Do the query
    if (!mysqli_query($conn, $query)) exit("Unable to update record in database");

  }

  // generate the form

  // Get original data from DB and store it in the session
  $query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $pkCol = $id";
  if (!$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)) exit("Unable to get record from database");
  $_SESSION['original_data'] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  $_SESSION['record_id'] = $id;

  // Echo start of HTML page
  echo "<html>

  <head>
    <title>Record update example</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form method='post' action=''>
      <input type='hidden' name='update' value='1' />
";

  // Generate inputs from data
  foreach ($_SESSION['original_data'] as $colName => $value) {
    if ($colName != $pkCol) {
      $colName = htmlspecialchars($colName);
      $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
      echo "      $colName: <input type='text' name='$colName' value='$value' /><br />\n";
    }
  }

  // Close off HTML
  echo "    </form>\n  </body>\n</html>";
```

Answer (score 1):

After submitting update form, you should to check values by firing a select query `where id = xyz` and then checking `if($_POST['textboxname'] == $row['colname'])`, if there is any changes found then add to update query other wise skip that value.

If you have had write your code here then this could be very easy to understand you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what Hossein suggested (+1, by the way) or you can mark the changed items somehow and you can map your items to your ID's.